# How to use dynamic CSS files with Nuxt?

Tags: javascript, css, vue-router, nuxt.js

I'm working in a project that have different users with their logos.
Based on the API call I want to load a different CSS with different colour palette.

Now I have a `css` folder inside `assets` folder with `main.js` (with my custom font styles, etc) and another files in there for the custom color palette: `<color-name>-palette.css`.

In my `nuxt.config` I'm calling the CSS colour like that:

```
  css: [
    '~/assets/style/app.styl',
    '~/assets/css/main.css',
    '~/assets/css/orange-palette.css'
  ],
```

Is there any way to bind the CSS file depending on the URL path/API call instead of putting the path there?

I'm not sure if I can use it on templates as well, binding the CSS files in there. Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To load CSS files dynamically, use `head()` instead of `head: {}`. That way, the values can be dynamic. Take a look the code below with working demo at https://codesandbox.io/s/l4on5508zm

```
<template>
  <section>
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <button @click="swap">swap</button>
    <p v-text="cur" />
  </section>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  head() {
    return {
      link: [
        {
          rel: "stylesheet",
          href: `/${this.cur}.css`
        }
      ]
    };
  },
  data() {
    return {
      cur: "light"
    };
  },
  methods: {
    swap() {
      if (this.cur === "light") {
        this.cur = "dark";
      } else {
        this.cur = "light";
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Looking at the code snippet above, you can bring in the css file to use on your page dynamically via the head() function. You can change the CSS to be used on the fly right on any page based on user interaction (for instance my button click interaction).

Answer (score 2):

You can use "head" in page component. https://codesandbox.io/s/xr55o4yqmq

```
<script>
export default {
  head: {
    link: [
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href: "/about.css"
      }
    ]
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Cool, I can put all my css files on head in the pages but how I can call the correct one based on the client API call/URL? =/